# How to Synchronously Wait for a Successful Fetch in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to perform a synchronous loop until a fetch to a URL is successful.
Here's what I've attempted:

```js
let res = null 

fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1").then((response)=>{
  return response.json();
}).then((data)=>{
  res = data;
  return data
})

while(!res){
  console.log(`${Date.now()} fetching`);
}
```

However, it doesn't work because the callback is not executed, leading to res = null.
How can I modify this to perform a synchronous loop until a fetch to a URL is successful?

Comment: you can't synchronously wait for an asynchronous result without a TARDIS (if you don't get the reference, it's a time machine, and you can't write a program that predicts the future)

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: The `while` loop blocks the entire event loop and that's why your callback is never executed.

Comment: I'm trying to perform a synchronous until a fetch to a URL is successful.

Comment: @hunglt.ee but why? You cannot turn asynchronous code into synchronous code. You've explained your attempted solution (the _"Y"_) but what is it you actually want to do with this code (the _"X"_)?

Comment: maybe for download progress?  something [like this](https://javascript.info/fetch-progress)

Comment: Once you go asynchronous, it's turtles all the way down.

Answer (score 1):

You can't synchronously wait for an asynchronous function in regular JavaScript.

JavaScript is single-threaded: different pieces of code do not run at the same time. Instead they are scheduled using an event loop. Further, the way the event loop works is that every piece of code [will run to completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop#run-to-completion) before picking up the next piece of code off the event queue. So, as you discovered, as your `while` loop cannot complete on its own, the runtime never has a chance to execute the callback: `while` just keeps on looping.

The good news is, you don't need to do what you are attempting. Whether you are using the browser or Node.js, the program won't exit while you are awaiting your `fetch` to complete (and of course, the browser runtime never exits). No waiting loop is needed.

Instead, simply add the code to do whatever you want to do with the data in your `then` callback and it will be executed when the data is received.

Comment: The code will run to completation, but i think we can use the res Promise has resolve state or something different.

Answer (score -1):

Hey looks like in the code example you're misusing the power of Promises.

I have 2 options that can help to make your code work.

1. Leverage the power of async/await syntax:

```
async function letsRock() {
   try {
      const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1")
      // The rest of your code ...
    
      return res // Return the response (Optional)

   } catch(e) {
     // Code in case that the request fails
   }
}
```

Note: Use `const` when possible.

**Documentation:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

2. Write your code inside the `.then` statement:

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1").then((response)=>{
  return response.json();
}).then((data)=>{
  // Use your data here this block defines that the function already was executed successfully 
})
```

**Note:** The code out of the function or `.then` block will continue executing and once the response comes back the code inside will too.

I hope it works for you!

Best Regards!

Answer (score -2):

I have modified your code. Once try this.

```
let res = null;
async function fetchData() {
    while(!res) {
        await fetch(url)
              .then((response)=>{
                   return response.json();
               }).then((data)=>{
                   res = data;
               })
    }
}

fetchData();
```

Comment: Now add a `console.log(res);` after your call to `fetchData()` and note how you haven't solved anything.

Comment: console.log(res) is a common thing. I thought it was not needed to mention.

Comment: The point is that it will log `null`. Your solution doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I got it. Please correct my answer.